# What the correct way to get size of binary data in php?

Tags: php

I've read a part of file and now want to make sure the part is the right size. How can I do it in php?

```
$part = fread($file, 1024);
return some_function($part) == 1024;
```

I've read the examples, but a I doubt to use strlen in cause of Null-terminated string, that might be inside the binary data in $part. In this way strlen returns size from start of part and until first null-byte is presented in data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the PHP manual, [strlen](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns the number of bytes in the string, not the character length.

In PHP, a null byte in a string does **NOT** count as the end of the string, and any null bytes are included in the length of the string.

So **strlen** can be used for binary data, no matter if the data is from a file or some other source.

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation of [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) function you may use the construction using [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) as shown in the first example:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Update: to find a size of the file can be used function [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) without opening or [fstat()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php) on opened file.

Comment: i need to know size of current part of file, but fstat/stat returns size of all file.